# Why was this packet sniffing question closed?

Tags: discussion, moderation, closed-questions

[How can I filter https when monitoring traffic with Wireshark?](https://serverfault.com/questions/263530/how-can-i-filter-https-traffic-with-wireshark)

Why was this question closed?  Seems perfectly valid to me...

Comment: thank you for your persistent interest in this matter

Comment: I would say this is too simple of a question, under the proposed guidelines at http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a lot of people alerted the moderators asking for it to be closed.

Comment: Since when is a lot of people alerting moderators a reason to close?  Isn't the point to alert a moderator and let them decide?  Besides, it was probably a lot worse before Doug's edit.  (I don't know because I don't have the rep to see it pre-edit.)  Consider reading it again and explaining the reason for closure, or re-open.

Comment: Part of moderating is about looking at what other users alert us about and using what little free time we give to the site to make the best judgements we can. We get hundreds of alerts per week and have limited time to deal with them, when we get multiple alerts from established high-rep users to a badly-written, one line question by a new user that's already been answered then it's an easy call to bring a close to the question. SF is a pretty democratic place, if enough people want a question closed or reopened then it happens even without moderators.

Comment: I understand that moderators are busy on a busy site like this.  What I don't get is that now that the question has been edited, why hasn't it been re-opened?  One-line question or not, it is a simple question that is perfectly valid.

Comment: I'll reopen it, because you're alerting me about it, but please understand that I closed it for the same reason - people asked me to. We can't know everything about every subject on this board but if a number of people say "this question shouldn't be open" and it's a low quality question, which it undoubtably is, then we have to listen.

Comment: Thank you, Chopper3.

Comment: @Brad, 'Since when is a lot of people alerting moderators a reason to close?' -- Always.  This is a community driven site.  If the community doesn't like it, or can't understand it, then it will most likely be closed.

Comment: @Zoredache, read through this chain again.  It has been established that the votes-to-close were made before the edit that clarified the question.  Additionally, I would like to point out that the community aspect (5 votes from those with lower rep) for closing was not reached.  The question was closed only on a moderator's opinion.  This doesn't matter though, as all of this has been cleared up.

Comment: votes to close wasn't 5, you're right, but we had four mod-alerts stating it wasn't a real question - in my mind actually mod-alerting with a comment is more effort than a single click and gets some extra credit, especially off established, high rep users.

Comment: @Brad - the answers its now gathered are arguably a saving grace but its a crap question that was rightfully closed imho. If the asker had put a quarter of the effort into asking a good question that you've put into complaining about a crap question being closed, then the question would actually be worthwhile and this discussion moot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know. I did a post-close edit to clarify the question and voted to reopen.  For 'not a real question' there were three solid answers. :)

The original question:

> I want to observe my first https protocol How can I use wireshark filter to do that?

Comment: Not really related to this one, but "Not a Real Question" is often what I pick when its something a SA really should know already.

Comment: If we judged every question by the number of answers then even worst of them would suddenly appear to be great questions. No, sorry, just because it was answered doesn't make it a good question, before or after the edit. Besides, the context suggests to me that the OP is not a professional admin. His bio confirms it. The question is therefore off-topic as well.

Comment: err.. I would not say 'three solid answers' when two of them are, literally "SEE THIS LINK! CLICK!"